# Getting value and name from list item for jQuery AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm generating a list of values from a DB like so:

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5 pure-u-lg-2-5 content-left">
  <div id="scroll" class="card">
  <a href="javascript:showhide('green')"><h2 class="is-center">green</h2></a>
    <ul id="greens" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
      <?php
      foreach ($greens as $green) {
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<input type='hidden' class='item_id' value='" . $green['id'] . "' name='" . $green['name'] . "'>";
        echo "<span class='item-name-small'>" . $green['name'] . "</span>";
        echo "<span class='item-description-menu'>" . $green['description'] . "</span>";
        echo "<span class='content-right'>";
        echo "</span>";
        echo "</li>";
      }?>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I have a jQuery function that attempts to grab the item that was clicked to pass onto another page:

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('ul.card-content-ingredients li').click(function(){
        var form_data = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
          url: "add-to-cart.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          data: form_data,
          success: function() {}
        });
      });
    });
  </script>
```

And I'm having a hard time sending the actual array. I've tried getting the elements info via `$(this).attr('id")` and that didn't work, I've tried to serialize and just grasping at straws now. What am I missing?

Exmaple: `var_dump($greens)`

```
array (size=31)
  0 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '19' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Almond Slices' (length=13)
      'description' => string 'TOASTED' (length=7)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001ce1' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '110' (length=3)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string '' (length=0)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '57' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Apples' (length=6)
      'description' => string 'Red Jacket' (length=10)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d21' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '20' (length=2)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string 'fruit' (length=5)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
  2 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '58' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Asparagus' (length=9)
      'description' => string 'STEAMED' (length=7)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d1e' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '0' (length=1)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string 'veggies' (length=7)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
  3 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '42' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Banana Peppers' (length=14)
      'description' => string '' (length=0)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001ce4' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '10' (length=2)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string 'veggies' (length=7)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
  4 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '43' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Beets' (length=5)
      'description' => string 'Fresh' (length=5)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001cde' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '30' (length=2)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string 'veggies' (length=7)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
  5 => 
    array (size=10)
      'id' => string '59' (length=2)
      'name' => string 'Black Beans' (length=11)
      'description' => string 'Organic' (length=7)
      'price' => string '0.65' (length=4)
      'nutritionix_id' => string '529e7dd1ea63d49335001d3f' (length=24)
      'nutritionix_cal' => string '35' (length=2)
      'active' => string '1' (length=1)
      'ingredienttype_id' => string '2' (length=1)
      'subtype' => string 'veggies' (length=7)
      'in_stock' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: thats because youre not creating your input array correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem I see, is that your JS code is written assuming you are submitting a form, but in reality you are not.

Let me give you a quick explanation on forms. Normally, when a form is submitted it looks at the input elements for the `name` attribute. So for example if you have a form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="some_link.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput1" value="myvalue1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="myinput2" value="myvalue2"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

When the "submit" button is clicked, the focus will be on its parent `form`, it will look at the method(in this case POST) and collect all input names within the form to create an array. If the input names do not exist, it will ignore it, if the names are the same, it will rewrite the last name. In the example provided, when the form is submitted, the following POST array will be sent to PHP as so:

```
array (size=2)
  'myinput1' => string 'myvalue1' (length=1)
  'myinput2' => string 'myvalue2' (length=1)
```

This will work great if you had forms in your HTML, but you don't. So the JS code `$(this).serialize()` will not work since `serialize()` assumes you submitted a form. I would do away with the FORM structure and rewrite your HTML so that we can then manually send information through AJAX like this:

```
<ul id="greens" class="card-content-ingredients">
    <?php foreach ($greens as $green) { ?>
        <li>
            <span class='item_id' style='display:none'><?= $green['id'] ?></span>
            <span class='item-name-small'><?= $green['name'] ?></span>
            <span class='item-description-menu'><?= $green['description'] ?></span>
            <span class='content-right'></span>
        </li>
    <?php } ?>
</ul>
```

So far, we iterate through the items to create an `li` that holds that item's information, specifically the ID, NAME, and DESCRIPTION of the item. Each item element has a class in your case: `item_id` ,`item-name-small`, `item-description-menu`. Now you need to ask yourself, when I send this information to `add-to-cart.php` should I just sent the ID or send all the information I already requested from the database? I would just send what you already have so that you dont make yet another database query. Therefore the code needs to collect all the information when the `li` is clicked. To collect the item info and send it to PHP through AJAX, I would create the following JS:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('ul.card-content-ingredients li').click(function () {
            var postdata = {
                id: $(this).find('.item_id').text(),
                name: $(this).find('.item-name-small').text(),
                description: $(this).find('.item-description-menu').text()
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: "add-to-cart.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: postdata,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

PHP should now be able to receive that POST request like this:

```
<?php
$id = $_POST['id'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
```

Hopefully with all this said, you are now able to submit your AJAX requests. Let me know if this all works for you, and if not, I can continue to explain in more depth.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I tried that I'm still not seeing anything in POST: empty array.

Comment: youre welcome can you `var_dump($greens);` and tell me what you get?

Comment: I just edited my post with the var_dump from array greens.

Comment: ok now im confused.. what are you trying to do when you run ajax?

Comment: I have a scrollable div that lists ingredients. When a person clicks on one of the ingredients, I would like it to be displayed in another div. The reason I'm using ajax is because my add-to-cart.php will add the total for the order, with the ingredients and display the full nutritional information. Is there a better way to accomplish this?

Comment: i think its a good idea but im just wondering why you are setting the name of the item as the key to your array. Perhaps it will make sense if i see the code to your PHP script, can you add that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89491/discussion-between-abard-and-codegodie).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a solution may have been achieved and was found in chat, but for any future on-lookers, and just to throw my 2-cents in, I'm going to post what I think you were trying to get at.

Pretty sure I see the whole issue. It appears you're wanting to send an array of information for each item selected. I'd recommend against that, since you can already retrieve that info server-side. It'd be better just to send the id of the item so you can retrieve its info server-side. However, if you still want to retrieve full array, I'll show you that too.

> For basic ID retrieval:

**First** *I'd recommend a little rewrite of your PHP/HTML*

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5 pure-u-lg-2-5 content-left">
    <div id="scroll" class="card">
    <a href="javascript:showhide('green')"><h2 class="is-center">green</h2></a>
        <ul id="greens" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <!-- Change the inline PHP to be a little more friendly in use, and remove all that echoing -->
            <?php foreach ( $greens as $grn ): ?> <!-- the : is like {, but for inline -->
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="<?php echo $grn['id']; ?>" name="greens" /> <!-- Here I make a generic name you can search by for IDs that you'll use to get that info again -->
                    <span class="item-name-small"><?php echo $grn['name']; ?></span>
                    <span class="item-description-menu"><?php echo $grn['description']; ?></span>
                    <span class="content-right"></span>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

With that little change, not only does it make it a little easier to write the HTML, it also pinpoints exactly what you'll be looking for server-side. That said, I would only make one little change to your jQuery.

**Change**

```
$('ul.card-content-ingredients li').click(function(){
    var form_data = $(this).serialize();
```

*To*

```
$('ul.card-content-ingredients li').click(function(){
    var form_data = $(this).find('index').serialize();
```

That will make server-side retrieval VERY EASY! On your server side, you should then simply have something like:

```
$greensID = $_POST['greens'];
$greensInfo = retrieve_greens_info_from_id($greensID);
//  then just make a function, whereby you simply
//  pass in the id, make your pull the array
//  shown in your question, and simply grab the one
//  with the matching ID!
```

> If you want an array of info, *then it gets a lil more dicey*.

There are different ways you can do this. Some would say you could add each item as inline, HTML5 *data* attributes. However, that could get hairy in dealing with apostrophes and code ugliness in debugging client side, and one thing after another. Personally, if this was criteria and I couldn't just use the ID, then I'd use a little JS/jQuery magic to help.

Like so:

**Main HTML**

```
<div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-md-2-5 pure-u-lg-2-5 content-left">
    <div id="scroll" class="card">
    <a href="javascript:showhide('green')"><h2 class="is-center">green</h2></a>
        <ul id="greens" class="card-content-ingredients" style="list-style-type: none;">
            <!-- Change the inline PHP to be a little more friendly in use, and remove all that echoing -->
            <?php foreach ( $greens as $grn ): ?> <!-- the : is like {, but for inline -->
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" class="item_id" value="<?php echo $grn['id']; ?>" name="greens" /> <!-- Here I make a generic name you can search by for IDs that you'll use to get that info again -->
                    <span class="item-name-small"><?php echo $grn['name']; ?></span>
                    <span class="item-description-menu"><?php echo $grn['description']; ?></span>
                    <span class="content-right"></span>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- script after -->
<script>
    $(function() {
        var greens = <?php echo json_encode($greens); ?>;   //  this gives you a js object of the greens arrays
            //  see reference below for what it'll look like
        $('#greens li').each(function(i) {  //  i is index
            $(this).data( 'nfo', greens[i] );   //  this get all the info for this item
            //  this is what you'll need to grab for your jQuery Ajax
        });
    })
</script>
```

**Then, in your *Ajax* call**

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#greens li').click(function(){
            var nfo = $(this).data('nfo'),  //  here we retrieve all the info for this item
                form_data = $.param(nfo);   //  this will make your data nice and tidy and easy to grab server-side!
            $.ajax({
                url: "add-to-cart.php",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: form_data,
                success: function() {}
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Then, on the **server-side**, simply get from **POST** like:

```
$gID = $_POST['id'];
$gName = $_POST['name'];
$gDesc = $_POST['description'];
//  and so on, and so on
```

**JSON Object of *greens* will look like:**

```
var greens = {
    "id": "19",
    "name": "Almond Slices",
    "description": "TOASTED",
    "price": "0.65",
    "nutritionix_id": "529e7dd1f9655f6d35001ce1",
    "nutritionix_cal": "110",
    "active": "1",
    "ingredienttype_id": "2",
    "subtype": "",
    "in_stock": "1"
}, {
    "id": "57",
    "name": "Apples",
    "description": "Red Jacket",
    "price": "0.65",
    "nutritionix_id": "529e7dd1f9655f6d35001d21",
    "nutritionix_cal": "20",
    "active": "1",
    "ingredienttype_id": "2",
    "subtype": "fruit",
    "in_stock": "1"
}, {
    "id": "58",
```